# Power Station for home

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-storage

I am looking to calculate what I need to power an average home (110-120V - 100 AH) using a LiFePo4 based power station. The units are 5000W and puts out 1575 AH. By using two units in parallel I can get 31.5 hours of 100 AH service, but I am questioning the voltage demand of a whole house. The battery units are 51.2 V. The inverters are built into the units and pulling the 110/120V is no problem. Is there something here I am not considering?

Comment: Try not to confuse AH and A. Also you probably know that W=AxV. The battery units are probably rated on battery voltage, so their energy content is 1575 times whatever the battery voltage is, not 1575 times 120V. There are two things to consider: whether your batteries can store a day's worth of energy (how much do you use in a day?) and the other is whether they can power the maximum things you use at once without overloading (I think this second one is what you calculated)

Comment: Hello and welcome. "puts out 1575 AH" /  "the voltage demand of a whole house" ... from your phrasing, may I suggest a good primer on voltage, current, power and energy in order to get all the parts straight?  A very good way to find out how much your house is using is use your existing electricity meter -- I used a time lapse function on my camera to takes pictures every minute for a week, once midsummer, once midwinter so I could draw good graphs of my demand.

Comment: Gregg, I'm going to just take what you wrote and project some of my own interpretations on it and then do a ***sanity-check***. Let's assume that the \$51.2\:\text{V}\$ and the \$1.575\:\text{kA-hr}\$ figures are descriptive of your power station. Then this means about \$80\:\text{kW-hr}\$.

Comment: Gregg, A [Tesla PowerWall 2 datasheet](https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/pdfs/powerwall/Powerwall%202_AC_Datasheet_en_northamerica.pdf) specifies \$14\:\text{kW-hr}\$. So my first sanity check suggests to me that you are talking about a very expensive unit that is equal to about ***(5)*** Tesla  PowerWall units. Since these are about \$\text{US}$10\:\text{k}\$ apiece. So this suggests to me that you have a ***lot of money*** to spend on this. Where is the datasheet on these units??? I'd like to see it.

Comment: Gregg, I'm not saying it's not possible. The Ford F-150 Lightening is impressive. It sports anywhere from \$98\:\text{kW-hr}\$ to \$131\:\text{kW-hr}\$.  But it is also priced out near \$\text{US}$100\:\text{k}\$, too. If you are spending that kind of money, you should have access to a datasheet on the unit. Please provide it. From there, we can do you much better service in analysis.

Comment: Gregg, Just skimming the web I found [these 200 AH 3.2 V](https://www.evlithium.com/Sinopoly-Battery/352.html) batteries. It would take 16 of them in series to get 51.2 V. Then 8 parallel bunches to reach what you are talking about. So this is 128 of these batteries in a system. Sounds like, anyway. That, plus everything else it takes to harness all that into a useful system. Pricey. Just the batteries alone for one such system are over US$30k.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is no average house. Where in the world is this house? Your voltage statement is indicating a pre WWII home in the US. We use a Split phase 220V system in the US. How big is the family? What is the real load? Is an HVAC system involved, if so how much does it require? The voltage demand is based on where in the world it is. Wattage demand is what you need to figure and at what voltage must it be supplied. Determine the proper battery chemistry, temperatures etc enter into this. This is just a start of what you need to know. The pros will probably get angry but ask for an estimate to have one installed. Then if you want it have them install it for you.

Comment: Isn't it 120/240 in the North America?

Comment: My home has 100 A service into the panel.

Comment: What type of system is it. I have a 100A branch panel at work but it is 3 Phase 480. you have a 100A panel ???? more information is needed. Split phase in the US gives you 120V from phase to neutral and 220V from phase to phase. Post a picture of the power coming from edison and of your 100A panel.